# iphone development: reaching objects from different viewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, imageview, viewcontroller

In my app, I have a problem, it sounds simple but I could not solve it. Well, here is the situation.

I have two viewControllers. VC1 and VC2. In VC1 I have a button and an imageView. When the button is pressed, the imageView moves from left to right with an animation and the VC2 is opened by pushtoViewController. in VC2 there is also a button which is a back button and when it is pressed it should open the first VC1 and the image should move from right to left.

I can open the VC1 by using PopViewController however I cant control the imageview from the VC2 so that I can animate it from right to left. How can I reach the imageView of the VC1 from VC2?

Comment: you could add a delegate method to VC2, that gets called when VC2 is popped. making VC1 the delegate of VC2 and writing the animation into this delegate method should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer quite correct, but I've another solution.

You could override VC1's `viewDidAppear:` message with something like that:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (imageView.frame.origin.x > 0.0) {
        // make your animation here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how to call your VC2 in VC1:

```
  VC2 *vc2 = [[VC2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC2" bundle:nil ];
  vc2.delegate = self; // here you set the delegate for the coming back call
  [self presentModalViewController: vc2 animated: YES]; // or however you present your VC2
```

And this is how you come back from vc2 to vc1, you call:

```
[self.delegate vc2HasFinished];
```

For this to work you need to create a protocol like this:
in `VC2Protocol.h`

```
 @protocol VC2Protocol <NSObject>
    -(void)vc2HasFinished;
    @end
```

Then you include this  `VC2Protocol.h` in VC1 and VC2. In VC1 you have to define this method like this:

```
-(void) weitereRufNrVCDidFinish{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];

}
```

This is the cleanest and recommended way by Apple - It looks cumbersome - I agree - but it works and you get used to it :-)

Comment: DismissViewControllerAnimated:completion is the recommended way. The dissmissModelViewControllerAnimated is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you - certainly you are right - I modiified the answer to reflect the new way...